# Does the order of inputs to the LSTM model affect the model.predict?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Here are two different inputs.

`signal_data = df[["close", "volume"]].values.astype('float32')`

`signal_data = df[["volume", "close"]].values.astype('float32')`

When the model is configured with LSTM, I wonder if the above two differences affect `model.predict.`

I noticed a difference when using `inverse_transform`. I wonder if I used `inverse_transfrom` incorrectly or if the order of input into the model affected `model.predict`.

Your valuable opinions and thoughts will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing stock market stuff? are "close" and "volume" for stocks?

Comment: And what is your Y?

Comment: stock market yes,  `x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
x_test, y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)` and  `def create_dataset(signal_data, look_back=20):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(signal_data) - look_back):
        dataX.append(signal_data[i:(i + look_back), :])
        dataY.append(signal_data[i + look_back, -1])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)`

Comment: No, I really don't think there is any difference between them.